# Image alignment not successful using OpenCV Orb

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-registration

I have two images of the same PCB (printed circuit board) taken from different perspectives (but not like drastically different though).

I tried to align the two images using OpenCV’s Orb feature detector. But the outcome was not so great: the homography matrix obtained from Orb features did not give rise to two aligned images. The difference image looked abysmal: there was a huge translation from one PCB to another. I then used cv::matchTemplate() to eliminate the translation. But the effects of rotation and projection still remained.

This is weird, considering the Orb feature finder (which is said to be a very adequate *patent free* replacement of SIFT and SURF) works fairly well with image stitching, which contains image alignment as a first step: there is no visible seam in a stitched panorama thereby obtained, meaning that the above situation where two images were so badly aligned is entirely contradictory. 
Below Are the template PCB image, the test image, the image absdiff(template - test registrated), and the interest point images

Hoping someone could give a little insight into how this might be...
[image: template image][image: test image][image: difference image][image: keypoints2]
[image: keypoints1]

Comment: Help I’m drowning :(

Comment: can you post the two images to litterally see the problem ?

Are your feature enough strong to make the transformation ? 
How is your threshold score use to pair two feature ?

Comment: @lamourettejean-baptiste coming right up

Comment: @lamourettejean-baptiste done! Could you use your expertise to point out what possibly went wrong?

Comment: @lamourettejean-baptiste So you are saying that images that are too textured could result in weak features?

Comment: @lamourettejean-baptiste I handcrafted the second pic by using warpPerspective(). (You can see bottom and right edges bending a little cause I put very small values into the (3 1) and (3 2) entries of the 3*3 homography matrix.) After detecting the features I used matcher.match() and bundle adjustment to calculate homography and then refine it...

Comment: Depending on the images resolution, using any warp or rotation will induce some kind of resampling -> loss of precision.

Comment: your file is very textured what is really a good point to make feature research.
you're supposed to got a score for each matching features, you can filter more striclty your feture match by fixing the matching threshold higher. You can work with bigger sized feature, cause you have a lot of feature that repeats like around small holes in top right it can make computer fails by matching wrong feature themselves.
can you display features detection and the features matching on both images. Like this
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html

Comment: @s.k I chose bicubic interpolation. The keypoint locations looked fairly identical though.

Comment: In reality, if the result you obtain is near that the representation you fake, the alignement in rotation is validate.
If it's just a problem of translation remaining. You can detect where are the top left corner of first image and top left corner on second image and make the translation corresponding to the deltaposition between both images

Comment: @lamourettejean-baptiste whoa. Your last comment helped massively. So the root of evil is that some features were too much alike, and the matcher got confused. Goosebumps.

Comment: can you now display the new result with new params ?

Comment: I’d love to but you see um, it’s 2 o’clock now here in China, and I was thinking I’m done for the evening  if I have my answer... Going to bed now. So maybe tomorrow?

Comment: @lamourettejean-baptiste Hi! Just posted the images with keypoints. Would be great if you helped analyze them a little. Thanks!